# How to disable warning C4927 in VS2013 Community

Tags: c++, c++11, warnings

I'm receiving the following warning in my project:

```
warning C4927: illegal conversion; more than one user-defined conversion has been implicitly applied while calling the constructor 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::basic_string(const _Elem *)'
      with
      [
          _Elem=char
      ]
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstring(778) : see declaration of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::basic_string'
```

I understand why it's happening, I'm just unable to suppress it. I've tried adding it to the Disable Specific Warnings list in my project settings, and I've also set my warning level to Turn Off All Warnings (/W0), yet the warning persists. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to hide the message?

Comment: Can you post the line in code that generates this warning

Comment: While your question is valid, I question your intention. Level 1 warnings are severe warnings that should never be disabled.

Comment: I went far out of my way to suggest that I was only interested in suppressing the warning. The code in question was this grotesque class that had every possible type operator and constructor required to automagically convert between wchar_t*, wstring, char*, and string. I noted during its brief existence that a warning appeared which was seemingly impervious to all IDE settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can control Visual Studio warnings directly in code using `#pragma warning` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx). If you'd like to silence the warning for a single line, you can put the following immediately before the line:

```
#pragma warning (suppress: 4927)
line-that-causes-warning-4927
```

You can also disable it from any point past the `#pragma`, by using 'disable' instead of 'suppress'. However, as the comments suggest, it's better to actually fix the warning, because it could be causing issues in your program.